# Problem displaying an image in adapter class in android studio using glide

Tags: java, android, image, adapter

I have two text views and two image views that has to show up in a particular post. The text View shows up correctly, but I see a blank space where the image should be.
Here is the adapter class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    List<Advertisement> mData ;
    Uri imguri;
    String url;
    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Advertisement> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_post_item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(row);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvProduct.setText(mData.get(position).getProductName());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(mData.get(position).getProductDescription());
        /*url=mData.get(position).getProductImageUrl();
        imguri = Uri.parse(url);
        holder.imgPost.setImageURI(imguri);*/
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getProductImageUrl()).into(holder.imgPost);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvDescription;
        TextView tvProduct;
        ImageView imgPost;
        ImageView imgPostProfile;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_post_description);
            tvProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_post_product);
            imgPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_post_img);
            imgPostProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_post_profile_img);
           
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the row_post.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_img"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/row_post_profile_img"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_profile_img"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#050505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note : I checked that I do get a url through the method getProductImageUrl() .
Please help me on how to rectify this problem. Been stuck on it for a while now

This is the Advertisement class

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep;

@Keep
public class Advertisement {
    private String productName;
    private String productDescription;
    private String productImageUrl;
    public Advertisement(String productName,String productImageUrl,String productDescription)
    {
        this.productName=productName;
        this.productImageUrl=productImageUrl;
        this.productDescription=productDescription;
    }
    public Advertisement()
    {
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Advertisement{" +
                "product_Name='" + productName + '\'' +
                ", product_Image_URL='" + productImageUrl + '\'' +
                ", product_Description='" + productDescription +
                '}';
    }
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public String getProductImageUrl() {
        return productImageUrl;
    }

    public void setProductImageUrl(String productImageUrl) {
        this.productImageUrl = productImageUrl;
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the database
[image: dataBase]

Comment: Please, share the `row_post_item.xml` also.

Comment: I have posted now

Comment: Did you check if the url contains valid image or not?

Comment: Can you share the `Advertisement.class` and database structure.

Comment: the url does contain a valid image..it loads in another activity that I use

Comment: I have added the class and db structure